# Remove a node from the current branch and add to another branch

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux-firebase

I have written the following code to remove a node from the current branch and add it to a different branch. But it only removes the node from the current branch without adding it to the new one.

```
export const unregister = id => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    registeredUsersRef.child(id).on("value", snapshot => {
      unregisteredUsersRef.child(id).set(snapshot.val()).then(()=> {
        registredUsersRef.child(id).remove();
      });
    });
  };
};
```

What can I do to set the data in a new branch before removing?

**Edit**: It seems that data is set to the unregisteredUsers branch but it is removed as soon as the data is removed from the registeredUsers. What can I do to avoid it?

Comment: So you're saying that `unregisteredUsersRef.child(id).set(snapshot.val())` doesn't work?  Could you go into more detail about what you're trying to do, and how you're observing that the code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: With the code I have written, i observed in the firebase console that the child from registeredUsers is removed but it is not set as a new child of unregisteredUsers. I want the child to be added to unregisteredUsers and then remove it from registeredUsers.

Comment: If the `remove()` runs, that means the `unregisteredUsersRef...set()` must have completed successfully. Are you sure `unregisteredUsersRef` points to the path you're looking at?

Comment: It seems that data is set to the unregisteredUsers branch but it is removed as soon as the data is removed from the registeredUsers.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a complete example.  Where are registeredUsersRef and unregisteredUsersRef created?  Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?